# Trace the implementation of a function to find value of sine

Tags: javascript

I am reading [SICP in javascript](https://source-academy.github.io/sicp/split/) and an exercise to find approximation of sine:

```js
function abs(x) {
    return x >= 0 ? x : -x;
}

function cube(x) {
    return x * x * x;
}
function p(x) {
    return 3 * x - 4 * cube(x);
}
function sine(angle) {
    return !(abs(angle) > 0.1)
           ? angle
           : p(sine(angle / 3));//p for procedure
}
```

run it and get:

```
> sine(1.57)
0.9999999959705563
> sine(3.14/6)
0.5000259145195963
```

How could I trace the running of sine(1.57) as it does in scheme?

```
> (trace sine)
> (sine 1.57)
|(sine 1.57)
| (sine 0.5233333333333333)
| |(sine 0.17444444444444443)
| | (sine 0.05814814814814814)
| | 0.05814814814814814
| |0.17365800071127369
| 0.5000259145195963
|0.9999999959705563
0.9999999959705563
```

Comment: Where are you running this code?  I'm pretty sure there are plenty of Javascript debuggers out there, in which case you can just set a breakpoint and step through the execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the return value in a variable and print it. You can use optional parameters to define the level of intendation

```js
function abs(x) {
    return x >= 0 ? x : -x;
}

function cube(x) {
    return x * x * x;
}
function p(x) {
    return 3 * x - 4 * cube(x);
}
function sine(angle, showTrace = false, indentationLevel = 1) {
  const indentString = Array(indentationLevel).fill('|').join(' ');
    console.log(indentString, `sine(${angle})`);
  const returnValue = !(abs(angle) > 0.1)
           ? angle
           : p(sine(angle / 3, showTrace, indentationLevel + 1));//p for procedure
    console.log(indentString, returnValue);
    return returnValue;
}

console.log(sine(1.57, true));
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in `trace` function, but it can be implemented using a monkey-patching mechanism (which is probably similar to how it's usually done in Lisp).

```js
const traced_functions = {};

function trace(funcname) {
  if (funcname in traced_functions) {
    console.log(`${functioname} is already being traced.`);
    return;
  }
  traced_functions[funcname] = {
    orig: window[funcname],
    depth: 0
  };

  window[funcname] = function(...args) {
    traced_functions[funcname].depth++;
    let prefix = Array(traced_functions[funcname].depth).fill('|').join('');
    console.log(`${prefix}${funcname}(${args.join(', ')})`);
    let result = traced_functions[funcname].orig(...args);
    console.log(`${prefix}= ${result}`);
    traced_functions[funcname].depth--;
    return result;
  }
}

function untrace(funcname) {
  if (funcname in traced_functions) {
    window[funcname] = traced_functions[funcname].orig;
  } else {
    console.log(`${funcname} is not traced`);
  }
}

function abs(x) {
  return x >= 0 ? x : -x;
}

function cube(x) {
  return x * x * x;
}

function p(x) {
  return 3 * x - 4 * cube(x);
}

function sine(angle) {
  return !(abs(angle) > 0.1) ?
    angle :
    p(sine(angle / 3)); //p for procedure
}

trace('sine');
sine(1.57);
```

This only works for global functions, since it requires the function name to be equivalent to `window[funcname]`.

Comment: That's neat, you're dynamically rewritting the function and copy the original one?

Comment: That's pretty smart, I didn't know that pattern, thanks